# Java background music from jar file

Tags: java, jar, wav

I am trying to implement background music that starts when i being my program and keeps on looping It works perfectly when i run the program from netbeans, however i could not get it to work when i run the jar file. Any ideas how to make it work with my current implementation? Thanks

In the main method i call this:

```
Sound sound = new Sound(); 
if (sound.setSong("resources\\music.wav")) { sound.start(); }
```

Here is the sound class:

```
public class Sound extends Thread {

private AudioStream as; 
private AudioPlayer p; 
private boolean playback;

public void run() { startPlayback(); }

public boolean setSong(String b) {
    try { 
        File a = new File(System.getProperty("user. dir") + "\\src\\" + b);
        if (a.exists()) { 
        // HERE THERE IS THE IMPLEMENTATION WHEN RUN FROM NETBEANS
            as = new AudioStream(new FileInputStream(a));
            return true; 
            } else { // HERE SHOULD BE THE JAR FILE IMPLEMENTATION
            as = new AudioStream(this.getClass().ge tResourceAsStream(b));
            return true;
            }
     } catch (Exception ex) { 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error in loading\n" + ex.getMessage());
        } 
        return false; }

public void startPlayback() { 
    playback = true; 
    p.player.start(as); 
    try { 
        do { } while (as.available() > 0 && playback);
        if (playback) { startPlayback(); } 
    } catch (IOException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(Sound.class.g etName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }    
}

public void stopPlayback() { playback = false; p.player.stop(as); } }
```

Comment: I realize he's trying to fix the formatting but obviously(?) it can't find the wav file because of the way it loads the resource.  Either the wav file isn't in the JAR file, or the path to the WAV file doesn't match the relative path from the .class file to the WAV file inside the jar context.

Answer (score 0):

When the app is packaged as a jar, the sound file is probably not in a "resources" folder - it is probably in the root of the classpath. So, you should probably do `sound.setSong("music.wav")`.

Unless you specifically want to try to load the file from the file system first, you probably don't need to do that - NetBeans should add it to the classpath.

Also, please be aware that back-slashes in Java Strings are escape sequences, not path separators.
So, if you want to specify a path, it's "/a/b", ***not*** "\a\b"

Comment: the resource i want to load is in the folder resources, called music.wav the relative path is the same even when inside the jar file. it's more a thing of accessing the jar file contents i believe

Answer (score 0):

In both cases (netbeans and jar), you should be able to call

```
as = new AudioStream(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/" + b));
```

Comment: you're welcome.  Please remember to "accept" this answer as a correct one.  Thanks!